# robustlmm function rlmer() too slow

Tags: r, mixed-models, robust

I want to conduct a mixed model with robust standard errors in a dataset with 45,000 rows. When I try to run the below code using rlmer() from the robustlmm package, it doesn't produce any result within 10 minutes (and probably longer). Y is continuous 1-12, x is binary, and PID is continuous 1:3000.

```
rlmer(y ~ x + (1|ID), data=dta_long)
```

Thank you in advance,

Benji

edit: the model runs fine when I use just the first 100 rows of the dataset. Looks like I just need someway to make it speedier.

Comment: How big is the dataset `dta_long`? Did you try with some small sample data first?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried it with just the first 100 rows and it produced a result. The full dataset is 45,000 rows.

Comment: And how many columns? Three?

Comment: Yep, just three columns.